# ProcessStartInfo and UseShellExecute usage

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to execute shell commands in a c# application:

```
try
{
    Process prc = new Process();
    prc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    prc.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
    prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    prc.Start();
    prc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(stream);
    prc.WaitForExit();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}
```

It works if I enter commands like 'ipconfig' or 'whoami'. But when I enter for example 'dir' I get a:

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified`

Any idea why? What's the trick here?

Answer (score 4):

Since dir is a command within cmd.exe you can't start it by it self , but you can execute it like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe","dir");
```

Comment: is ipconfig an executable or a command within cmd.exe? same for whoami...

Comment: @idontcare yes, they are both `exe` files sitting generally at `%Windir%\System32\ ` . You can easily check it from the command line using (for example): `where ipconfig`, or `where whoami`. In this case: `where dir` will tell you it won't find the file